# To place into involuntary servitude

Tags: phrase-requests

To place a man into involuntary servitude by taking away all of his freedoms, with no regard to his interests, is to **enslave** him.

To place a man into involuntary servitude by taking away only his freedom to refuse work, with no regard to his interests, is to place him into **peonage**.

If we place a man into involuntary servitude by taking away only his freedom to refuse work, how can we describe this arrangement **without saying anything about whether the arrangement represents his interests**?

Perhaps great care was taken to respect his desires, hopes and ambitions in finding a job placement within a planned economy legal framework enforcing transparent negotiations and the right to appeal. Perhaps not.

There might not be a single word to describe this notion completely and unambiguously. I am looking for a small, minimally emotive vocabulary to describe various aspects of this topic: how do we refer to each the parties involved? What do we call the document that makes the arrangement official? What is the action of placing someone into this arrangement?

References to real instances of societies that have attempted to implement this kind of system would be especially appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like voluntary servitude to me. Either you consult the laborer as to his interests, and give the option of not entering into servitude, or you force him into servitude, which, though not slavery, is kidnapping, even if it turns out that he likes the job.

Comment: http://www.pbs.org/tpt/slavery-by-another-name/themes/peonage/

Comment: @BrianHitchcock The laborer in that example merely expresses preferences to a system that forces him to work in an assigned job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest word I can think of is [indenture](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indenture) - *A contract binding one party into the service of another for a specified term.*

Answer (score 1):

I would still call that enslavement.  The definition of enslavement is to take away the slave's freedom.  It is usually assumed that this arrangement is beneficial to the master and detrimental to the slave, but I don't believe that the connotation is strictly part of the definition.

Practitioners of slavery have often rationalized their actions with justifications that it's for the slaves' own good, with arguments like "Slaves are too uneducated to run their own lives properly" or "Slavery would be better than starving to death".

---

If you're talking about a society in which the government removes freedom of choice in certain matters (though not forced labour) for the people's own good, you could call it a *nanny state*.